# Any way to retrieve Visual Studio production key?

Tags: windows, license, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 Pro with retail key. I have built new PC and moved there. I was hoping VS has attached the key to my Microsoft account but it hasn't.

I cannot find the key.

I still have the old PC running. Is there any way I can recover the key from the registered Visual Studio or from my Microsoft account?

*both PCs run Windows 10 and being used under same Microsoft account, if it helps*

Comment: Check i this location HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Registration.
check under PIDKEY

Comment: PIDKEY is empty..

Comment: Have you tried MagicJellyBean finder?

Comment: solved it by finding old email with the KEY.. I don't like installing free exe like MJB - it works as I heard. But simply don't install anything unless its totally unavoidable.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50480361/45552

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to find the activation key under the registry path `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\4D8CFBCB-2F6A-4AD2-BABF-10E28F6F2C8F\07062` . The value is encrypted though, so you need to decrypt it with the `CryptUnprotectData` method in the Win32 API.

I have created a small tool that simplifies this and should allow extracting product keys for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 (only tested for 2019 professional so far):

https://github.com/terjew/VSKeyExtractor

Comment: Thank you! I tried accessing the PIDKEY located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Registration\xxxxx` first (because it's listed everywhere) but that didn't work. This, however, did the trick.